# Why this code is generating array index out of bound?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I am stuck for past 5 - 6 hours in figuring this out that why this code is generating array index out of bound error on run time. I am unable to find out the reason. Can you please tell what modifications are required to correct this code?

```
spotsArr        := make(map[int][]map[int64][]int)
for ind, availableSpot := range availableSpots {
            spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid][ind] = make(map[int64][]int)
            spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid][ind][availableSpot.Date] = []int{availableSpot.SpotSlug}

}
fmt.Println(spotsArr)
```

**Edit 1**: View the full code here https://play.golang.org/p/Smm0BFgtNp

**Edit 2**: Actually what I need to do is to get output in format something like:

```
{ uid: { date: {spot_slug, spot_slug} } }

{ 86: { 1536710400: {1000, 1200, 900},
      { 1536105600: {900} } }
```

Comment: a short but complete code demonstrating the index out of bound error in [playground](https://play.golang.org/) would be perfect. A lot of other errors occurred when I try to create one : https://play.golang.org/p/HdkjoU0KXy

Comment: @har07 thanks for the response buddy, please check the code, I have updated the question.

Comment: Could you say what do you want to get as a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is, as the error message suggests, because you tried to assign element on the index greater than the slice length. For the sake of getting the error away, you can just initialize the slice to the length, at least, as much as the index you wanted to use :

```
....
spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid] = make([]map[int64][]int, ind+1, ind+1)
spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid][ind] = make(map[int64][]int)
....
```

But as you clarified further about the desired output, it seems that you don't need slice in the first place. You need *map of `Uid`* where each key has value of *map of `Date`* :

```
spotsArr := make(map[int]map[int64][]int)
for _, availableSpot := range availableSpots {
    if _, ok := spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid]; !ok {
        spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid] = make(map[int64][]int)
    }
    spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid][availableSpot.Date] = append(spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid][availableSpot.Date],availableSpot.SpotSlug)
}
fmt.Println(spotsArr)
```

**<kbd>[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yTqm2O1eay)</kbd>**

Given the last two data have the same date, the output is as follows :

```
map[86:map[1534896000:[900] 1535500800:[900] 1536105600:[900] 1537315200:[900 900]]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot har07, you saved tons of my time. Kudos! :)

Answer (score 0):

spotsArr is a map of int to an array of maps - map[int][]...

```
spotsArr        := make(map[int][]map[int64][]int)
```

On this line, you try to assign to an index of that array which has no members yet:

```
spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid][ind] = make(map[int64][]int)
```

You're saying set this spot availableSpot.Uid to something (fine) but then set the index ind in an array which doesn't have members to something else (not fine). To fix this I'd recommend trying to do less on each line so that it's much clearer where and what the problem is. You could do this to fix the grammar error:

```
spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid] = []map[int64][]int{make(map[int64][]int)}
```

But I can't think why you want to set an index on the map to the index of the Uids you're traversing (your code doing [Ind]). I'd try to make this less complex and confusing if you can and spread it out on several lines to make the intent clear.

PS Give people a code sample which runs (i.e. include all the structs used), it makes it easier to help.

PPS Thanks for code sample, that makes it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kenny, I have shared the complete code here: https://play.golang.org/p/Smm0BFgtNp, it might help

Comment: I also dont want to use `ind` for that purpose but if I leave it blank it given " unexpected ], expecting expression" error, Just for now to avoid that I was passing it through. How can i accomplish this so that array should pick up the indexes itself?

Comment: I replaced the line `spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid][ind] = make(map[int64][]int)` with `spotsArr[availableSpot.Uid] = []map[int64][]int{make(map[int64][]int)}` but I am still facing the error.